# Using ctags and cscope

Tags: c++, ctags

I did a ctags -R on my project which is in c++, in the directory /project/ntopng. Now, when I start cscope using cscope -R and search for main.cpp, it opens up. But, when I hit ctrl-] on #include "ntop-includes.h" in main.cpp, the error message is tag not found. The header file is inside a sub-directory in /project/ntopng/include. But, ctags -R is recursive so why is it that I am getting an error? I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with the latest version of ctags and cscope. Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

I have given the below answer for `Ubuntu 12.04`

```
1. Open any file with vim
2. type :echo &tags ,It will show what path vim is using for tags file.
```

If it is not the expected tag file path type: 
`:set tags=path_to_your_tag_file   (ex /project/ntopng/tags)`

Remember it is valid for the current session only, Now if permanent changes required there are two options.

For All users (requires root privileges) --

```
1. cd /etc/vim
2. vim vimrc
3. Go to end and add set tags+=tags;path_to_your_tag_file
```

For the individual user:

```
1. cd ~
2. vim .vimrc    (This file may not exists in that case newly created)
3. set tags+=tags;path_to_your_tag_file
```

Let me know if it worked for you.